# Using scrapy recursivelly for scrape a phpBB forum

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping

I'm trying to use scrapy for crawl a phpbb-based forum. My knowledge level of scrapy is quite basic (but improving).

Extract the contents of a forum thread's first page was more or less easy. My successful scraper was this:

```
import scrapy

from ptmya1.items import Ptmya1Item

class bastospider3(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "basto3"
    allowed_domains = ["portierramaryaire.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://portierramaryaire.com/foro/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3821&st=0&sk=t&sd=a"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//div[2]/div'):
            item = Ptmya1Item()
            item['author'] = sel.xpath('div/div[1]/p/strong/a/text()').extract()
            item['date'] = sel.xpath('div/div[1]/p/text()').extract()
            item['body'] = sel.xpath('div/div[1]/div/text()').extract()
            yield item
```

However, when I tried to crawl using "next page" link I have failed after a lot of frustrating hours. I would like to show you my attempts, in order to ask for an advice. *Note: I would prefer to obtain a solution for the SgmlLinkExtractor variants, since they are more flexible and powerful, but I priorize success after so many attempts*

**First one**, SgmlLinkExtractor with restricted path. 'Next page xpath' is

```
/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/fieldset/a
```

Indeed, I tested with the shell that

```
response.xpath('//div[2]/form[1]/fieldset/a/@href')[1].extract()
```

returns a correct value for the "next page" link. However, I want to note that the cited xpath offers **TWO** links

```
 >>> response.xpath('//div[2]/form[1]/fieldset/a/@href').extract()
[u'./search.php?sid=5aa2b92bec28a93c85956e83f2f62c08', u'./viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3821&st=0&sk=t&sd=a&sid=5aa2b92bec28a93c85956e83f2f62c08&start=15']
```

thus, my **failed** scraper was

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

from ptmya1.items import Ptmya1Item

class bastospider3(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "basto7"
    allowed_domains = ["portierramaryaire.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://portierramaryaire.com/foro/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3821&st=0&sk=t&sd=a"
    ]

    rules = (
            Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//div[2]/form[1]/fieldset/a/@href')[1],), callback="parse_items", follow= True)
            )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//div[2]/div'):
            item = Ptmya1Item()
            item['author'] = sel.xpath('div/div[1]/p/strong/a/text()').extract()
            item['date'] = sel.xpath('div/div[1]/p/text()').extract()
            item['body'] = sel.xpath('div/div[1]/div/text()').extract()
            yield item
```

**Second one**, SgmlLinkExtractor with allow. More primitive and unsuccessful too

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

from ptmya1.items import Ptmya1Item

class bastospider3(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "basto7"
    allowed_domains = ["portierramaryaire.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://portierramaryaire.com/foro/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3821&st=0&sk=t&sd=a"
    ]

    rules = (
            Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3821&st=0&sk=t&sd=a&start.',),), callback="parse_items", follow= True)
            )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//div[2]/div'):
            item = Ptmya1Item()
            item['author'] = sel.xpath('div/div[1]/p/strong/a/text()').extract()
            item['date'] = sel.xpath('div/div[1]/p/text()').extract()
            item['body'] = sel.xpath('div/div[1]/div/text()').extract()
            yield item
```

**Finally**, I returned to the damn paleolithic age, or to its first tutorial equivalent. I try to use the loop included at the end of the beginner's tutorial. Another failure

```
import scrapy
import urlparse

from ptmya1.items import Ptmya1Item

class bastospider5(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "basto5"
    allowed_domains = ["portierramaryaire.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://portierramaryaire.com/foro/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3821&st=0&sk=t&sd=a"
    ]

    def parse_articles_follow_next_page(self, response):
        item = Ptmya1Item()
        item['cacho'] = response.xpath('//div[2]/form[1]/fieldset/a/@href').extract()[1][1:] + "http://portierramaryaire.com/foro"
        for sel in response.xpath('//div[2]/div'):
            item['author'] = sel.xpath('div/div[1]/p/strong/a/text()').extract()
            item['date'] = sel.xpath('div/div[1]/p/text()').extract()
            item['body'] = sel.xpath('div/div[1]/div/text()').extract()
            yield item

        next_page = response.xpath('//fieldset/a[@class="right-box right"]')
        if next_page:
           cadenanext = response.xpath('//div[2]/form[1]/fieldset/a/@href').extract()[1][1:]
           url = urlparse.urljoin("http://portierramaryaire.com/foro",cadenanext)
           yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse_articles_follow_next_page)
```

In **all the cases**, what I have obtained is a cryptic error message from which I cannot obtain a hint for the solution of my problem.

```
2015-10-08 21:24:46 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://portierramaryaire.com/foro/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3821&st=0&sk=t&sd=a> (referer: None)
2015-10-08 21:24:46 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://portierramaryaire.com/foro/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3821&st=0&sk=t&sd=a> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 577, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 76, in parse
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
2015-10-08 21:24:46 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

I really would appreciate any advice (or better, a working solution) for the problem. I'm utterly stuck on this and no matter how much I read, I am not able to find a solution :(

Answer (score 2):

The cryptic error message occurs because you do not use the `parse` method. That's the default entry-point of scrapy when it wants to parse a response.

However you only defined a `parse_articles_follow_next_page` or `parse_item` function -- which are definitely no `parse` functions.

And this is not because of the next site but the first site: Scrapy cannot parse the `start_url` so your tries are not reached in any case. Try to change your `parse_items` to `parse` and execute your approaches again **for the palaeolithic solution**.

If you are using a `Rule` then you need to use a different spider. For those use `CrawlSpider` which you can see in the tutorials. In this case do not override the `parse` method but use the `parse_items` as you do. That's because `CrawlSpider` uses `parse` to forward the responses to the callback method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I try your solution changing the first scraper from `parse_item` to `parse` in both definition and callback, but the error message is the same.


I found different tutorials in which `parse` is changed to `parse_whatever`, and they apparently work. For instance, http://mherman.org/blog/2012/11/08/recursively-scraping-web-pages-with-scrapy/#.VheBHvntlBc.

I wonder if the problem is related with the construction and/or type of the url given to callback...

Comment: Updated the answer. When using rules you need a different spider type -- the basic `scrapy.Spider` won't work.

Comment: Thanks again. The first spider import crawlSpider. Of course, I adapted it from other examples. The error message persists :(

Comment: Importing is not enough. You have to extend your spider: `class bastospider3(CrawlSpider):`.

Comment: GHajba, thanks a lot!!!!! I had to change what you said, and also had to add a comma at the end of the rule in order to avoid the error message `exceptions.TypeError: 'Rule' object is not iterable`. The rule looks like this: `Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//div[2]/form[1]/fieldset/a')), callback="parse_item", follow= True),`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [GHajba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3941341/ghajba), the problem is solved. The solution is developed on the commentaries.

However, the spider doesn't return the results in order. It starts on http://portierramaryaire.com/foro/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3821&st=0&sk=t&sd=a

and it should walk through "next page" urls, which are like this: http://portierramaryaire.com/foro/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3821&st=0&sk=t&sd=a&start=15

incrementing the 'start' variable with 15 post each time.

Indeed, the spider returns first the page produced 'start=15', then 'start=30', then 'start=0', then again 'start=15', then 'start=45'...

I am not sure if I have to create a new question or if it would be better for future readers to develop the question here. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

since this is 5 year old - many many new approaches are out there.

btw: see https://github.com/Dascienz/phpBB-forum-scraper

> Python-based web scraper for phpBB forums. Project can be used as a
> template for building your own custom Scrapy spiders or for one-off
> crawls on designated forums. Please keep in mind that aggressive
> crawls can produce significant strain on web servers, so please
> throttle your request rates.
>
> The phpBB.py spider scrapes the following information from forum
> posts: Username User Post Count Post Date & Time Post Text Quoted Text
> If you need additional data scraped, you will have to create
> additional spiders or edit the existing spider.
>
> Edit phpBB.py and Specify: allowed_domains start_urls username &
> password forum_login=False or forum_login=True

see also

```
import requests
forum = "the forum name"

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
payload = {'username': 'username', 'password': 'password', 'redirect':'index.php', 'sid':'', 'login':'Login'}
session = requests.Session()

r = session.post(forum + "ucp.php?mode=login", headers=headers, data=payload)
print(r.text)
```

**but wait**: we can - instead of manipulating the website using requests,
also make use a browser automation such as mechanize offers this.
This way we don't have to manage the own session and only have a few lines of code to craft each request.

a interesting example is on GitHub https://github.com/winny-/sirsi/blob/317928f23847f4fe85e2428598fbe44c4dae2352/sirsi/sirsi.py#L74-L211